Getting a TypeError when running my chatbot code
This is my code for a chatbot I'm creating. I keep getting a "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'" error when running it however.
def pre_process_data(data):
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(data)
    tokens = [word.lower() for word in tokens]
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    tokens = [
        word for word in tokens if word not in stop_words and word not in string.punctuation]
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    tokens = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in tokens]
    return tokens


def predict_answer(model, tokenizer, question):
    question = pre_process_data(question)
    sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([question])
    padded_sequence = pad_sequences(
        sequence, maxlen=sequence_length, padding='post', truncating='post')
    prediction = model.predict(padded_sequence)[0]
    index = numpy.argmax(prediction)
    answer = tokenizer.index_word[index]
    return answer


while True:
    question = input('You: ')
    answer = predict_answer(model, tokenizer, question)
    print('Chatbot:', answer)

I'm not too sure what I've done wrong here ):
The full error code is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Chatbot\main.py", line 119, in <module>
    answer = predict_answer(model, tokenizer, question)
  File "D:\Chatbot\main.py", line 109, in predict_answer
    padded_sequence = pad_sequences(
  File "D:\Chatbot\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\sequence_utils.py", line 125, in pad_sequences
    trunc = np.asarray(trunc, dtype=dtype)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'


Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

The error message is telling you that one of the parameters you are passing in to the library function in the padded_sequence is None, i.e. it has no value. You need to use your debugger to find which one it is and why.

Hi@Reina297, You are facing an error when  you are trying to convert a sequence to an integer array using numpy,In your code you are using pad_sequences() make sure the shape is correct and model.predict() should be a numpy array of probabilities ,check it if you are still facing an issue let me know,Thanks.
